# Checking reader if has data not working

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have used MysqlDataReader to read data from mysql database however, whenever i coded it in different ways it still reads data incorrectly. 
This program is  scheduling system, i used datetimepicker for time and date input, then the user will click the button CHECK to check if it has already exist in the database/not available schedule else it will tell the user that the schedule is available

```
Dim reader1, reader2 As MySqlDataReader

MySqlConn.Open()

Dim query2, query1 As String

Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand

    'TIME
    query1 = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE Date ='" & dtpDate.Text & "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query1, MySqlConn)
    reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
    reader1.Close()

    query2 = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE Time ='" & dtpTime.Text & "'"
    cmd2 = New MySqlCommand(query2, MySqlConn)
    reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader


    If reader1.HasRows And reader2.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("A Patient already set an appointment for this schedule! Please set another Time & Date.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Schedule exists")
        dtpTime.Select()

    ElseIf reader1.HasRows = 0 And reader2.HasRows = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Schedule is available!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Schedule")

    ElseIf reader1.HasRows = 0 And reader2.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Schedule is available!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Schedule")

    ElseIf reader1.HasRows And reader2.HasRows = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Schedule is available!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Schedule")
    End If

    MySqlConn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You only need one query. Combine the Date and Time fields if they are separated.

Answer (score 0):

Uou are closing your reader1 before checking the conditions. The readers should be closed after "reading" them

Comment: but when i remove reader1.close there is an error at reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader it says " There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." what should i do?

Comment: Then use a temporal variable to store the values yo want to evaluate from the first reader and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

Check both fields in one query. Use Parameters to avoid sql injection attacks.

```
query1 = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE [Date] = @date And [Time] = @time"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dtpDate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("time", dtpTime.Text)
```

Comment: after that code you've given, what's next? and what condition should i use in iF ELSE statement?

Comment: If this returns something then it seems there is an appointment right?